# how to restrict google places autocomplete to specific country?

Tags: android, google-places-api

I want to restrict my goolge places auto complete api to the specific country only now iam getting the entire world suggestion places ... Please solve the problem thanks in advance

## Place Adapter class:-

```
package com.example.keita.googleplaces;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Filter;
import android.widget.Filterable;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.Status;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompleteFilter;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePrediction;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.AutocompletePredictionBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class PlaceArrayAdapter
        extends ArrayAdapter<PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete> implements Filterable {
    private static final String TAG = "PlaceArrayAdapter";
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private AutocompleteFilter mPlaceFilter;
    private LatLngBounds mBounds;
    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> mResultList;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param context  Context
     * @param resource Layout resource
     * @param bounds   Used to specify the search bounds
     * @param filter   Used to specify place types
     */
    public PlaceArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, LatLngBounds bounds,
                             AutocompleteFilter filter) {


        super(context, resource);
        mBounds = bounds;
        mPlaceFilter = filter;
    }

    public void setGoogleApiClient(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
        if (googleApiClient == null || !googleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient = null;
        } else {
            mGoogleApiClient = googleApiClient;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mResultList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public PlaceAutocomplete getItem(int position) {
        return mResultList.get(position);
    }

    private ArrayList<PlaceAutocomplete> getPredictions(CharSequence constraint) {
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Executing autocomplete query for: " + constraint);
            PendingResult<AutocompletePredictionBuffer> results =
                    Places.GeoDataApi
                            .getAutocompletePredictions(mGoogleApiClient, constraint.toString(),
                                    mBounds, mPlaceFilter);
            // Wait for predictions, set the timeout.
            AutocompletePredictionBuffer autocompletePredictions = results
                    .await(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            final Status status = autocompletePredictions.getStatus();
            if (!status.isSuccess()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Error: " + status.toString(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e(TAG, "Error getting place predictions: " + status
                        .toString());
                autocompletePredictions.release();
                return null;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Query completed. Received " + autocompletePredictions.getCount()
                    + " predictions.");
            Iterator<AutocompletePrediction> iterator = autocompletePredictions.iterator();
            ArrayList resultList = new ArrayList<>(autocompletePredictions.getCount());
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                AutocompletePrediction prediction = iterator.next();
                resultList.add(new PlaceAutocomplete(prediction.getPlaceId(),
                        prediction.getDescription()));
            }
            // Buffer release
            autocompletePredictions.release();
            return resultList;
        }
        Log.e(TAG, "Google API client is not connected.");
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        Filter filter = new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
                if (constraint != null) {
                    // Query the autocomplete API for the entered constraint
                    mResultList = getPredictions(constraint);
                    if (mResultList != null) {
                        // Results
                        results.values = mResultList;
                        results.count = mResultList.size();
                    }
                }
                return results;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                    // The API returned at least one result, update the data.
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                } else {
                    // The API did not return any results, invalidate the data set.
                    notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                }
            }
        };
        return filter;
    }

    class PlaceAutocomplete {

        public CharSequence placeId;
        public CharSequence description;

        PlaceAutocomplete(CharSequence placeId, CharSequence description) {
            this.placeId = placeId;
            this.description = description;
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return description.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

## MainActivity class:-

```
package com.example.keita.googleplaces;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.Html;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Place;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.PlaceBuffer;
import com.google.android.gms.location.places.Places;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MainActivity";
    private static final int GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID = 0;
    private AutoCompleteTextView mAutocompleteTextView;
    private TextView mNameTextView;
    private TextView mAddressTextView;
    private TextView mIdTextView;
    private TextView mPhoneTextView;
    private TextView mWebTextView;
    private TextView mAttTextView;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private PlaceArrayAdapter mPlaceArrayAdapter;
    private static final LatLngBounds LAT_LNG_BOUNDS = new LatLngBounds(
            new LatLng(32.6393,-117.004304), new LatLng(44.901184 ,-67.32254));


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .addApi(Places.GEO_DATA_API)
                .enableAutoManage(this, GOOGLE_API_CLIENT_ID, this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .build();
        mAutocompleteTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id
                .autoCompleteTextView);
        mAutocompleteTextView.setThreshold(3);
        mNameTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name);
        mAddressTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.address);
        mIdTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_id);
        mPhoneTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.phone);
        mWebTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.web);
        mAttTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.att);
        mAutocompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(mAutocompleteClickListener);
        mPlaceArrayAdapter = new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                LAT_LNG_BOUNDS, null);
        mAutocompleteTextView.setAdapter(mPlaceArrayAdapter);
    }
    private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener mAutocompleteClickListener
            = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final PlaceArrayAdapter.PlaceAutocomplete item = mPlaceArrayAdapter.getItem(position);
            final String placeId = String.valueOf(item.placeId);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Selected: " + item.description);
            PendingResult<PlaceBuffer> placeResult = Places.GeoDataApi
                    .getPlaceById(mGoogleApiClient, placeId);
            placeResult.setResultCallback(mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback);
            Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Fetching details for ID: " + item.placeId);
        }
    };

    private ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer> mUpdatePlaceDetailsCallback
            = new ResultCallback<PlaceBuffer>() {
        @Override
        public void onResult(PlaceBuffer places) {
            if (!places.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Place query did not complete. Error: " +
                        places.getStatus().toString());
                return;
            }
            // Selecting the first object buffer.
            final Place place = places.get(0);
            CharSequence attributions = places.getAttributions();

            mNameTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getName() + ""));
            mAddressTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getAddress() + ""));
            mIdTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getId() + ""));
            mPhoneTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(place.getPhoneNumber() + ""));
            mWebTextView.setText(place.getWebsiteUri() + "");
            if (attributions != null) {
                mAttTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(attributions.toString()));
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(mGoogleApiClient);
        Log.i(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connected.");

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection failed with error code: "
                + connectionResult.getErrorCode());

        Toast.makeText(this,
                "Google Places API connection failed with error code:" +
                        connectionResult.getErrorCode(),
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mPlaceArrayAdapter.setGoogleApiClient(null);
        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Google Places API connection suspended.");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

## content_main.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.keita.googleplaces.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:hint="Enter Place Here"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/autoCompleteTextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Selected Place:"
        android:textStyle="bold"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/place_id"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/address"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/place_id"
        android:autoLink="phone"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/web"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/phone"
        android:autoLink="web"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/att"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:autoLink="web"/>

    ImageView
        android:id="@+id/poweredBy"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/att"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/powered_by_google_light"/>

    ImageView
        android:id="@+id/truiton_image"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/poweredBy"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 18):

In Android we can restrict in this way:

Add **AutoCompletionFilter** in you code instead passing **null**

---

*To restrict google places autocomplement to Australia.*

```java
AutocompleteFilter filter = 
    new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setCountry("AU").build();
```

**The country to restrict results to. This should be a ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 country code (case insensitive). If this is not set, no country filtering will take place.**
Refer this link for different country codes https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2

***@Saipraneeth Nandi*** Correct the line your code as below:

```java
mPlaceArrayAdapter = 
    new PlaceArrayAdapter(this, 
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            LAT_LNG_BOUNDS,
                            filter);
```

Comment: Thanks. made my day :)

Answer (score 7):

Just add this to your query you are sending to google places api:

```
components=country:your_country_code
```

You can find country code [here](https://countrycode.org/).

**Example**:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=bhubaneshwar&components=country:in&sensor=false&key=your_key
```

Let me know if this is what you want.

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

```
private String country = "IN";

Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, Arrays.asList(Place.Field.ADDRESS, Place.Field.LAT_LNG))
                .setCountry(country)
                .build(YourActivity.this);
startActivityForResult(intent, 214);
```

[Get Country Code & Latitude Longitude](https://developers.google.com/public-data/docs/canonical/countries_csv)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in the URL builder

`String countryCode = ((TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(
                                Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE)).getNetworkCountryIso();
     urlBuilder.addQueryParameter("components", "country:" + countryCode);`